# Transforming Logs for Clickpath Analysis using Hive

Tags: hive

I have click logs that look like this:

```
        userID     time                    URL  
           1       2011-03-1 12:30:01      abc.com
           2       2011-03-1 12:30:04      xyz.com
           1       2011-03-1 12:30:46      abc.com/new
           2       2011-03-1 12:31:02      xyz.com/fun
           2       2011-03-1 12:36:08      xyz.com/funner
           1       2011-03-1 12:45:46      abc.com/newer
```

I want to convert this to clickpath data organized by session (defined as any series of clicks that begins after a 10 minute gap since that user's last click) because I want to run clickpath analyses.  Here's the intended result:

```
        userID     sessionStart           clicktime               Seconds       fromPage          toPage
          1        2011-03-1 12:30:01     2011-03-1 12:30:01      NULL          NULL              abc.com
          1        2011-03-1 12:30:01     2011-03-1 12:30:46      45            abc.com           abc.com/new
          1        2011-03-1 12:30:01     NULL                    NULL          abc.com/new       NULL
          1        2011-03-1 12:45:46     2011-03-1 12:45:46      NULL          NULL              abc.com/newer
          1        2011-03-1 12:45:46     NULL                    NULL          abc.com/newer     NULL
          2        2011-03-1 12:30:04     2011-03-1 12:30:04      NULL          NULL              xyz.com
          2        2011-03-1 12:30:04     2011-03-1 12:31:02      58            xyz.com           xyz.com/fun
          2        2011-03-1 12:30:04     2011-03-1 12:36:08      306           xyz.com/fun       xyz.com/funner
          2        2011-03-1 12:30:04     NULL                    NULL          xyz.com/funner    NULL
```

Notice there are two distinct sessions for user 1 due to the 10+ minute gap between the 2nd and 3rd clicks.

I thought I found a solution using Hive's [windowing features](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics#LanguageManualWindowingAndAnalytics-LEADusingdefault1rowleadandnotspecifyingdefaultvalue) from version 0.11, but I'm working with version 0.10 and so now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Hive [transform](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Transform) function, with a custom reducer script.
You'll have to ensure that all the lines with the same user_id are processed by the same reducer, using the [distribute by function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy#LanguageManualSortBy-SyntaxofSortBy), and that the lines are sent in ascending date order, using the [sort by](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy#LanguageManualSortBy-SyntaxofSortBy) function.

```
ADD FILE hdfs:///path/to/your/scripts/reducer_script.py ;
create table clickStream as 
select 
transform (a.user_id, a.time , a.url) 
USING 'reducer_sessionizer.py' as (user_id, time, url, fromPage, toPage)
from (select user_id, time, url from rawData distribute by user_id sort by time ) a ;
```

Your script, in python for instance, will read your dataset line by line, and you will process the data referring to the keys change :

```
sessionDuration = 10 minutes

for line_out in sys.stdin:
    str = []
    line_split = line_out.strip().split('\t')
# line_split = [userId, Time, Url]


# check the duration since last action, if above the sessionDuration, we create a new session Id
# check the user (the key) is still the same too, else, we create a new session Id
# we store the userId to compare on next iteration
    if (line_split[1] - prev_time > sessionDuration OR prev_user != line_split[0]) :
        sid = uuid.uuid4().hex
        prev_url = "Null"
        sess_start = line_split[1]
    else :
        pass

    str.append(line_split[0]) # userId
    str.append('\t')
    str.append(line_split[2]) # toPage
    str.append('\t')
    str.append(sess_start) # session start time
    str.append('\t')
    str.append(prev_url) # fromPage
    print "".join(str)

# for next iteration, we keep the previous userId, url and time
    prev_user = line_split[0]
    prev_time = line_split[1]
    prev_url = line_split[2]
```

(I'm not really a dev, so consider that as pseudo code, and I let you add the dates processing)